# How to collapse and expand collapsible files (XML, JSON) in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: json, xml, intellij-idea, editor

I have a fairly large XML, JSON, or any file format with structured data following the tree hierarchy. I want to collapse/expand **all** the items in IntelliJ Idea but I am lazy to do it manually, how to do it?

**XML:**

[image]

**JSON:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go is very simple, but it is not intuitive and visible as took me a while to find it out.

Open the file and navigate to the top bar **Code** -> **Folding** and a new panel would open with choices of expanding/collapsing either all or recursively.

[image]